# No data read from hdf5 in caffe prototxt

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5, pycaffe

I am trying to test my caffe model by feeding a blob with all ones in it. So I form a hdf5 file by:

```
import h5py, os
import numpy as np

SIZE = 227 # fixed size to all images

X = np.ones((1, 3, SIZE, SIZE), dtype='f8')

with h5py.File('test_idty.h5','w') as H:
    H.create_dataset('img', data=X ) 
with open('test_h5_idty_list.txt','w') as L:
    L.write( '/home/wei/deep_metric/test_idty.h5' )
```

Then, I change my caffe prototxt to be:

```
layer{
  name:"data"
  type:"HDF5Data"
  top:"img"
  include:{
    phase:TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param{
    source:"/home/wei/deep_metric/test_h5_idty_list.txt"
    batch_size:1
  }
}
```

Then, I try to make sure my data is fed correctly by:

```
net = caffe.Net(Model,Pretrained,caffe.TEST)
data = net.blobs['img'].data.copy()
```

However, this gives me all zeros in the matrix. 
Any idea on how to solve it?

Appreciated!

Comment: @ShaiThank you so much! I think I miss the forward function. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `"HDF5Data"` layer to read it's first batch you need to call `net.forward()` first. Once a forward pass is done, the `top`s of the layer has the data read from files.